# Aurelia: How to bind viewmodels of child DOM elements to parent's viewmodel?

Tags: aurelia

Is there anyway I can get a reference to all the viewmodels of the child  components in my `lanes` property on the `BoardComponent` viewmodel? I need to have a reference of al `<boardlane></boardlane>` in the viewmodel of the `<board></board>` component. Is this possible?

App.ts

```
export class App {
    public groups: any[] = [
        {
            title: 'first group'
        },
        {
            title: 'second group'
        }
    ]
}
<template>
    <board>
        <boardlane repeat.for="group of groups" title.bind="group.title"></boardlane>
    </board>
</template>
```

Board Component

```
@customElement('board')
export class BoardComponent {
    public lanes: BoardLaneComponent[];
}

<template>
    <div class="board">
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

BoardLane Component

```
@customElement('boardlane')
export class BoardLaneComponent { }

<template>
    <div class="boardlane">
        I am a board lane
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to select all `<boardlane>` elements and have their viewmodels referenced by a list contained on `BoardComponent` - have you looked into a child selector? It will watch for mutations in the `BoardComponent` view and maintain an observable list of child elements or child viewmodels (depending on if the element selected is an Aurelia backed element).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You are correct, that is exactly what I want! I have not looked into child selectors yet, but I will do that right away!

Comment: http://aurelia.io/docs/templating/custom-elements#decorators-for-customizing-aurelia-custom-element-processing - the docs are a bit thin on this, let me see if I can find an example

Comment: that would be nice!

Comment: https://github.com/aurelia/templating/issues/451#issuecomment-252258269 this one looks ok - basically it's a decorator you stick on the VM class - give it a `name` (the name of the property you want it to create/maintain on your VM) and a `selector` (the selector that points to the child elements) and it will maintain that property for you. The only caveat was that it wasn't working for nested elements at one point (e.g. grandchild vms/templates), I'm not sure if that still stands though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the `@children` decorator:

Board Component

```
import {children} from 'aurelia-framework';

@customElement('board')
@children({ name: 'lanes', selector: 'boardlane' })
export class BoardComponent {
    public lanes: BoardLaneComponent[];

    lanesChanged() {
        // Handle any mutations to the array here
    }
}

<template>
    <div class="board">
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

In theory this should maintain a list of child VMs on `BoardComponent` by using the selector to gather the elements within the view.

If the elements are non-aurelia backed elements they will be represented by `Element` instances in the specified array, otherwise they will be a reference to the actual Aurelia VM backing the element.

Also, it will by default create a function called `<x>Changed` where `<x>` is the name of the backing array. You can use this to be notified of any mutations happening to the tracked elements.

The only issue may be nesting - I believe the original implementation deep-selected into descendants but that was removed later. I'm not sure if it was re-introduced but the details are here:

https://github.com/aurelia/templating/issues/451

Assuming you don't need to go to grandchildren this should work.

**Disclaimer:** not done any Aurelia dev for a little while :(

**Note:** I don't think the docs clearly list the API for `children` and the `selectorOrConfig` parameter it takes

In the source it looks like this:

```
constructor(config) {
    this.name = config.name;
    this.changeHandler = config.changeHandler || this.name + 'Changed';
    this.selector = config.selector;
    this.all = config.all;
}
```

So it looks like the object can have those properties - not sure what `all` does though but interesting that you can change the name of the change handler that's fired when the array contents mutate.

Comment: Thanks for the effort! I managed to do it in a GIST. https://gist.run/?id=40dcf861e75857e7ab2aaa702cf1afb4. Something like this right?

Comment: @TomAalbers yeah looks good - I assume since you accepted that it's exactly what you wanted :), helps to know all the framework features!